# Duplicated output using printf() and fork() in C

Tags: c, linux, fork

I run this small program to test `fork()`, and I can't figure out the output, the program's code is:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 

int i = 0;
void create()
{
    fork();
    printf("Inside i= %d \n", i);
    i = i + 1;
    fork();
}
int main()
{
    create();  
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Inside i= 0 
Inside i= 0 
Inside i= 0 
Inside i= 0
```

Aren't there supposed to be just two outputs, because in the last `fork()`, the children has nothing to print out?

I've read that the process child will execute the next instruction, after the `fork()`, though the last children seems to have executed the `printf()` instruction.

Comment: Sorry did not understand you

Comment: I've reworded the question a bit to make it more clear and easier to find, hope you don't mind.

Comment: `printf()` is not threadsafe, so you should expect troubles.

Comment: @VillageTech thread safety has nothing to do with this. `fork()` does not create threads.

Comment: @Marco Bonelli - you are right, thanks.

Comment: Both the father process and the child process continue execution right after the call to fork(). For the sake of studying, if you want to know which process (child or father) is printing, add the current pid in your calls to printf(). E.g. printf("pid#%d: Inside i= %d \n", getpid(), i);

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The output of your program is highly implementation dependent.

The C standard library applies buffering to the output stream. This means that it accumulates characters to write until the buffer reaches a certain length (or until a certain condition is met), and then outputs all the text at once.

The most common behavior is to use *line buffering*, which means that the text will be printed out when a newline character (`\n`) is encountered. This is indeed what happens on my machine with your example. Since you `fork()` before the `printf()`, two processes execute the call and the output is immediately printed since there is a newline:

```
$ ./prog
Inside i= 0
Inside i= 0
```

The other `fork()` is then executed on each of the two processes, but there's nothing more to print out, since the internal output buffer has already been emptied, so nothing noticeable happens in this case.

However, depending on your specific implementation and the conditions in which the program is run, `printf()` (and in general any `stdio` function) could decide to apply different buffering rules.

For example, when piping the output to another program or to a file, glibc usually uses a fixed size buffer and does not do line buffering. Since the buffer is not filled with a single short `printf()`, the text is retained inside it to be printed later. When you `fork()` a second time, each of the new children gets a copy of said buffer, and all the text is then printed (by each one of them) when the process exits. On my system, when piping, this is the output:

```
$ ./prog | cat
Inside i= 0
Inside i= 0
Inside i= 0
Inside i= 0
```

If you want to make sure the text is printed right away, you can either use [`fflush()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) or disable buffering of `stdout` with [`setvbuf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html).

Examples:

- Using `fflush()`:

  ```
  void create()
  {
      fork();
      printf("Inside i= %d \n", i);
      fflush(stdout);
      i = i + 1;
      fork();
  }
  ```
- Using `setvbuf()`:

  ```
  int main()
  {
      setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
      create();  
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: @hyde yep right, though now imma do some researches about buffering and try to fix ideas, but i would not mind if any have a good explanation or an article to read.

Comment: @OussamaMater this is a good read: http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/, and also this one: https://eklitzke.org/stdout-buffering

Comment: The explanation for the second `fork()` is still not clear for me, I would say that the 2 process perform the write operation that's why there is 2 times the output. Also there is a duplicate 'the' in the 3rd paragraph.

Comment: @MickaelB. tried to make it cleared. Does it make sense to you now?

Comment: I have an off question, I'm new to stackoverflow and I got confused how my question got edited by @MarcoBonelli, for sure it's better now, but how, I did the tour and there's no such thing mentioned I guess.

Comment: @OussamaMater it is possible for users to edit other people's posts (nut just *their* posts). If you have less than 2000 reputation, the edit will need to be approved first, but if you have more it will be immediately applied. It is quite common for people to improve questions editing them to fix wording, typos, format etc.